# Can I open an application using Selenium?

Tags: java, sql, selenium, automated-tests

I'm writing a script for test automation which requires checking the back-end SQL database in the SQL Developer. Is it possible that I do this through selenium?  Selenium is a web automation..

If not, I can do this through java, right?

Comment: selenium is not designed for that. use java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using java with selenium you can use :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("//path to ur application")
```

Now further if that application has UI that you can get control on that using tools like **Autoit**.

Answer (score 3):

Selenium is only used for web browser it open web site in browser and record only website, it does not used for desktop application for desktop application you will be used Java or QTP.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think selenium can open desktop applications. It can only open browser depending on the input variable. You need to do it in java.